# Stripe payments, adding price from another model into payment method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongoid, stripe-payments

I have added Stripe payment to my app to handle registration payments for events, the form is on the event show page so the method is in the events controller but I have created a registration model. My issue is trying to get the price of the event into the `save_with_payment` method inside the registration model(`total_price`).

Any ideas? I have tried `attr_accessible :price` but with no luck.

### Event Controller

```
def show
  @event = Event.where(:slug => params[:slug]).first
  @registration = Registration.new
end

def payment
@registration = Registration.new(params[:registration])
if @registration.save_with_payment
    RegistrationMailer.admin(@registration, @event).deliver
    RegistrationMailer.delegate(@registration, @event).deliver
    redirect_to root_path
    flash[:success] = "Thank you for registering for <% @event.title %>"
  else
    redirect_to root_path
    flash[:error] = "We're sorry, something went wrong"
  end
end
```

### Registration Model

```
def save_with_payment
  if valid?
   charge = Stripe::Charge.create({
   amount: total_price, ##I can declare a integer here instead of a method and it works
   currency: "gbp",
   card: stripe_card_token,
   description: email })
   save
  end
 rescue Stripe::CardError => e
end

def total_price
  @event.price = price
  price
end
```

### Routes

```
match 'registration' => 'events#show', :via => :get
match 'registration' => 'events#payment', :via => :post
```

### View

```
<%= simple_form_for [@registration], :method => :post, :url => registration_path do |f| %>
<%= f.input :first_name %>
<%= f.input :last_name %>
<%= f.input :email %>
<%= f.input :job_title %>
<%= f.input :company %>
<%= f.input :stripe_card_token, as: :hidden %>
<div class="input card_number">
    <label for="card_number">Card number</label>
    <%= text_field_tag :card_number %>
</div>
<div class="input card_cvc">
    <label for="card_code">Security code (CVC)</label>
    <%= text_field_tag :card_cvc %>
</div>
<div class="input card_dates">
    <label>Card expiration date</label>
    <%= select_month nil, { add_month_number: true }, { id: "card_month"} %>
    <%= select_year nil, { add_year: Date.today.year, end_year: Date.today.year + 15 }, { id: "card_year"} %>
</div>
<%= f.button :submit, "Register", class: "button" %>
```

Comment: does registration `belong_to :event` ?

Comment: No, this doesn't work either.

Comment: Dan -- my question was yes or no, not an answer... How does event and Registration relate to each other in the database?

Comment: Apologies Jesse, they are not related. My client wants the form on the event show page so I thought I should include the actions within the event controller and then keep the create payment method inside a reg model. Can you advise where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

If I got everything right, here:

```
def show
  @event = Event.where(:slug => params[:slug]).first
  @registration = Registration.new
end
```

is controller action with view, containing form.

Registration should belong to event, I suppose, through `:has_one`

Then your registration model needs `event_id` integer column. As you declared `@event` in show, append you registration form with

```
<%= f.input :event_id, as: :hidden, value: @event.id %>
```

After that you can find `@event` in payment method by:

```
@event=Event.find(params[:registration][params[:event_id]].to_i)
```

This is basic example, I don't actually know, what is event in your app, may be there is better attribute which you can pass.

After that you can pass `@event.price` as argument to model method:

```
def save_with_payment(total_price)
  if valid?
   charge = Stripe::Charge.create({
   amount: total_price,
   #other code
```

Comment: My problem is I don't know how to access the event price inside the registration model. I added <code>(@event.price)</code> to the <code>save_with_payment</code> method and now I get undefined method `price' for nil:NilClass because event is nil.

Comment: @DanMitchell,  but then what do you expected by passing `@event` in deliver method?  your link to payment method should or contain id, or additiobal parametrs by which you can define instance `@event`, but with this background I can't tell more presicely

Comment: This has completely thrown me because I need the form on the event show page rather then a link to /registration/new I am stuck. I have updated the question with more information, the above code works for taking payment if I declare the amount but obviously I need to keep it dynamic by declaring a price for each of the events which is what I want the total price method to get. I appreciate any help and advice :)

Comment: @DanMitchell, what is relation between event and registration? What is event?

Comment: I am building an events website and I need people to buy a ticket to register. At present there is no relationship between the events and registration, except I am using the events controller to access the registration model which works.